# Save an Excel worksheet as csv automatically when it opens

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to save an Excel Worksheet as a csv automatically when the Excel file opens. Here's the code I am using. Please help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim wbkExport As Workbook
Dim shtToExport As Worksheet

ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")     
Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
Application.DisplayAlerts = False                     
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Kennedy\Desktop\Alinta\Testcsv\test1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is, place the following code on `ThisWorkbook` Module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim wbkExport As Workbook
    Dim shtToExport As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Set shtToExport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
    shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:=Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Alinta\Testcsv\test1.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```